# How long does it take Voximplant to detect a disconnected user?

Tags: voximplant

I am testing losing connection in a Voximplant call. The Disconnected event fires after approximately one minute after losing connection. Can I adjust this value?

Answer (score 0):

The server waits for the client to reconnect if the connection is lost. If you don't need this feature, you can send pings from the client via sendMessage and check for them for example each 2-3 seconds. If there are no pings, then use hangup